# Calculate the length of the portion of the hypocycloid $x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=1$

Tags: calculus

Calculate the length of the portion of the hypocycloid $x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=1$ in the first quadrant from the point $(\frac{1}{8},\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8})$ to the point (1.0)

$x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=1$

$y^{\frac{2}{3}}=1-x^{\frac{2}{3}}$

$y=(1-x^{\frac{2}{3}})^{\frac{3}{2}}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(1-x^{\frac{2}{3}})^{\frac{3}{2}}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac {3}{2}(1-x^{\frac{2}{3}})^{\frac{1}{2}}(0-\frac{2}{3}x)$

i am not sure where to go from there

Comment: What was the purpose of `## Heading ##` in your MathJax?

Comment: Im not sure what happened, i fixed it.

Comment: Do you know the [formula for arclength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating)?

Comment: Next go to the  arc formula $ \int \sqrt{1+y^{'2} }dx $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula for arc length is
$$L=\int_{\frac18}^1\sqrt{1+\left(y'\right)^2}dx$$
It is easy to find the derivative:
$$y'=-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{\frac23}}}{x^\frac13}$$
The length is now:
$$\begin{align}L&=\int_{\frac18}^1\sqrt{1+\left(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{\frac23}}}{x^\frac13}\right)^2}dx\\&=\int_{\frac18}^1x^{-\frac13}dx\\&=\left.\frac32x^\frac23\right|_\frac18^1\\&=\frac98\end{align}$$

[image]

Comment: How did you get y prime?

Comment: @MMM. It is $\frac {3}{2}(1-x^{\frac{2}{3}})^{\frac{1}{2}}(0-\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac13})$